# R - how to convert two `for` loops to `lapply`?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I have this code:

```
    getSomething = function(x, y) {
      return something
    }

    b = matrix(NA, nrow = ncol(a), ncol = ncol(a))

    # Loop through the columns
    for(i in 1:ncol(a)) {
      # Loop through the columns for each column
      for(j in 1:ncol(a)) {
        b[i, j] = getSomething(as.matrix(a[i]), as.matrix(a[j]))
      }
    }
```

It works just fine, but when I try to run the code on big datasets, it takes a very long time to run.

How to convert it to `lapply` function so that it can run faster?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `lapply`, look at `outer` which does these loops for you:

```
outer(seq(ncol(a)), seq(ncol(a)),
      FUN=function(i, j) getSomething(as.matrix(a[i]), as.matrix(a[j]))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still got error message: `dims [product 3249] do not match the length of object [1]` (3249 comes from 57 * 57, `a` has 57 variables with 200 observations).
Do I need to take into account the number of observations in `a`?